# Как вызывать функции OpenTk из другого потока?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, opentk

столкнулся с тем что выполняя вызовы GL в основном потоке ошибок не происходит, но как только начинаю вызывать из Task.Run то возникает ошибка "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." Или ошибка возникает когда я пытаюсь в деструкторе вызвать функции удаления текстуры

```
~Texture()
{
    GL.DeleteTexture(handle);
}
```

Данную ошибку удалось обойти с помощью статического класса в который я записываю handle в деструкторе, а само очищение вызываю каждый кадр из главного потока

```
public static class GarbageCollector
{
    private static Stack<int> Textures { set; get; } = new Stack<int>();
    public static void DeleteTexture(int handle)
    {
        Textures.Push(handle);
    }
    public static void ClearTextures()
    {
        while (Textures.TryPop(out int handle))
            GL.DeleteTexture(handle);
    }
}
```

Деструктор теперь выглядит так:

```
~Texture()
{
    GarbageCollector.DeleteTexture(Handle);
}
```

А каждый кадр вызываю очистку записанных текстур на удаление

```
protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnRenderFrame(e);
    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit|ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

    SwapBuffers();
    GarbageCollector.ClearTextures();
}
```

Возникает вопрос как вызывать методы класса GL из другого потока без таких танцев с бубном? И если из другого потока эти функции нельзя вызывать то в основном потоке нужно вызывать по возможности только функции видеокарты, а все остальные расчеты выносить на другие потоки связывая через такие статические классы?

П.С. Минимально воспроизводимый пример где при нажатии на кнопку Q мы удаляем в главном потоке буффер а при нажатии на кнопку W удаляем буфер в Task.Run

```
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4;
using OpenTK.Mathematics;
using OpenTK.Windowing.Common;
using OpenTK.Windowing.Desktop;
using OpenTK.Windowing.GraphicsLibraryFramework;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestOpenTk
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var nativeWindowSettings = new NativeWindowSettings
            {
                Size = new Vector2i(800, 600),
                Title = "My OpenTK Example Program"
            };
            using (var window = new GameWindowEngine(GameWindowSettings.Default, nativeWindowSettings))
            {
                window.Run();
            }
        }
    }

    public class GameWindowEngine : GameWindow
    {
        int VertexBufferObject;
        public GameWindowEngine(GameWindowSettings gameWindowSettings,
                              NativeWindowSettings nativeWindowSettings)
            : base(gameWindowSettings, nativeWindowSettings)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnUpdateFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnUpdateFrame(e);
            if (KeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Q))
            {
                GL.DeleteBuffer(VertexBufferObject);//Тут ошибки нет
            }
            if (KeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
            {
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    GL.DeleteBuffer(VertexBufferObject);//тут ошибка есть
                });
            }
            
        }

        protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnRenderFrame(e);
            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
            SwapBuffers();
        }

        protected override void OnLoad()
        {
            base.OnLoad();
            GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
            GL.ClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);

            VertexBufferObject = GL.GenBuffer();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: По этим маленьким огрызкам кода мало чего можно понять, но скорее всего дело не в потоках, так как показанная вами ошибка напрямую не связана с многопоточкой, скорее у вас просто баги потокобезопасности в коде, который вы не показали. Нужен воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: @aepot Добавил минимально воспроизводимый пример где при загрузке мы выделяем буфер а потом  удаляем его в главном потоке и в Task.Run

Comment: Удалось разобраться с контекстами?

Comment: @aepot К сожалению нет, пишет "WGL: Failed to make context current" хотя контексты и блокировки я добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня получилось заставить это работать.

```
public class GameWindowEngine : GameWindow
{
    int VertexBufferObject;
    public GameWindowEngine(GameWindowSettings gameWindowSettings,
                            NativeWindowSettings nativeWindowSettings)
        : base(gameWindowSettings, nativeWindowSettings)
    {
    }

    private readonly object _lock = new object();

    protected override void OnUpdateFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnUpdateFrame(e);
        if (KeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    Context.MakeCurrent();
                    GL.DeleteBuffer(VertexBufferObject);
                    Context.MakeNoneCurrent();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("DeleteBuffer success");
            });
        }

    }

    protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            Context.MakeCurrent();
            base.OnRenderFrame(e);
            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
            SwapBuffers();
            Context.MakeNoneCurrent();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnLoad()
    {
        base.OnLoad();
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
        GL.ClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        VertexBufferObject = GL.GenBuffer();
        Context.MakeNoneCurrent();
    }
}
```

При условии наличия взаимной блокировки, а стоит ли оно того? Решать вам.

Comment: Не работает, вот скрин кода https://i.ibb.co/VB3GtXL/image.png

Comment: @ИльяАнтипанов в конце OnLoad добавьте `Context.MakeNoneCurrent();`

Comment: Заработало, спасибо, попробую теперь в своем проекте расставить